# Get Instagram Access Token with android volley

Tags: android, instagram, access-token, android-volley

i use this code for post a request to instagram and get accesstoken.

```
URL url = new URL(tokenURLString);
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            outputStreamWriter.write("client_id="+CI +
                    "&client_secret="+ CS +
                    "&grant_type=authorization_code" +
                    "&redirect_uri="+CALLBACK_URL+
                    "&code=" + requestToken);
            outputStreamWriter.flush();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(StreamToString.get(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream()));
```

how can i do this with android volley ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ive just actually implemented this myself. This is the code i used.

```
    public void requestAccessToken(final String code) {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, TOKENURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Success Response = ", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error Response = ", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("client_id", CLIENTID);
            params.put("client_secret", CLIENTSECRET);
            params.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            params.put("redirect_uri", REDIRECTURL);
            params.put("code", code);
            return params;
        }
    };

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out this tutorial:

[Asynchronous HTTP Requests in Android Using Volley](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)
I used this in the first time I applied volley on a project. Volley is pretty straightforward to use.